# IGBT breakdown with induced transient voltage

Tags: capacitor, igbt

I have a circuit with four IGBTs model IXYT25N250CHV up to 2.5 kV  for a maximum working voltage of 1.5 kV

[image]

Each IGBT is used to charge a capacitor from a photovoltaic (PV) system at different voltage ranges, 200 V, 500 V, 1000 V and 1500 V, with a capacitor rated at that voltage. IGBTs are driven with UCC21520. I am having the issue that sometimes just by connecting a 1.5 kV PV string the 200 V channel IGBT is activated, 1500 V are connected to the 200V capacitors and they explode. I insist, this occurs just by connecting the PV system not by activating the IGBTs intentionally. Initially the IGBTs where off at 0 V and on at 12 V with a 10 kΩ resistor between gate and emitter and the failure rate was big. I detected induced noise  at the moment of connection all over the PCB and also on the IGBTs gate, with transients over the gate activation voltage so I thought the IGBT was being activated by this induced noise and connecting 1.5 kV to 200 V capacitors.

[image: Induced noise]

I changed the circuit so off voltage would be -12 V to make this more robust to induced voltages and changed the gate-emitter resistance to 2 kΩ and added a 4 nF capacitor (very close to the IGBT). This has reduced the failure rate but it still occurs sometimes and induced voltage is still at least over 15 V as shown in the image. What is curious is that it is always the IGBT in the 200 V channel that fails and not the 500 V o 1000 V ones, and they are all the same model and have the same driving circuit. In the PCB itself the 200 V IGBT is furthest from the driver so more noise could be induced but I am not sure this is the reason.

Comment: I've improved your first image but, there are things you might want to fix like 1.500 literally means one and a half when, I think you meant 1,500. Details are important.

Comment: _"I detected induced noise at the moment of connection all over the PCB"_ Please post your PCB layout.